# input type date format not working in chrome

Tags: html, reactjs

I have the following date input:

```
<input
    type="date"
    placeholder="DOB (DD/MM/YYYY)"
    //maxLength="100"
    className={`inputText ${styles.inputText}`}
    value={dob}
    onChange={(e) =>
        this.setState({
            dob: e.target.value,
        })
    }
/>
```

When i run it on my chrome or firefox, i get the correct output which is
[image]

however when my friend runs it on his chrome, he gets:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how I can fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding css for it...

**Option 1** - Add css for specific input on specific page with class.

**css :**

```
.my_input_date::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input
    type="date"
    placeholder="DOB (DD/MM/YYYY)"
    //maxLength="100"
    className={`my_input_date inputText ${styles.inputText}`}
    value={dob}
    onChange={(e) =>
         this.setState({
         dob: e.target.value,
         })
    }
/>
```

**Option 2 :**  for all input with type date on any page...

```
input[type="date"] ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually chrome's support for 'date' is broken. (See here). At least for the moment.

The use of 'date' in the HTML is absolutely fine - browser's which do not know of or support an input type are supposed to fallback to type='text'.

Currently chrome partially supports date, in a way that is essentially broken (it adds a couple of up-down buttons, but no datepicker.)

Of course you do need to bear in mind that if you are using type='date', and if the browser supports it, then you'll want to disable whatever datepicker support you'd otherwise be using.

UPDATE (6 Feb 2012):

It looks to me like this is now fixed. Chrome no longer claims to support input type='date', and does not provide the partially complete implementation.

UPDATE (17 Aug 2012):

Chrome does now have input type="date" support, and it's more functional this time.